# Average value of function

Tags: calculus

This is a homework problem and I'm not even sure where to start with it. The problem reads:

> Show that if $f(x)$ has period $p$, the average value of $f$ is the same over any interval of length $p$. Hint: $$\int_a^{a+p}f(x) dx$$ as the sum of two integrals ($a$ to $p$, and $p$ to $a+p$) and make the change of variable $x = t+p$ in the second integral.

Okay so I know how to write the hint out and I get the point that $f(t+p) = f(t)$ but what am I actually supposed to write out? I don't know out to transform this integral. Where do I start after writing out the 'hint'?

Comment: Can anyone help me in solving que 1 and 2?                              Also I am confused at one point.  In F(x+p) where p is period. It means that the function is at the point period plus x dist. Away. Hena ? So how can I put x= t+p for the limit p to p+a?  Period will be complete from a to p+a.   Not from p to p+a.. Then how can I take that value.  If I would go x dist. Further from a to p+a (i.e. One complete cycle) then I could take t+p= x

Comment: its not clear what you are asking , you havent posted Q 1 & 2 . please edit your question to include everything and make it clearer. Also try to keep it in english :P people wont understand "hena?"

Comment: I have attached photo of que. 1 n 2

Comment: Please use the [MathJax notation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) embedded in this site and *copy* the text into the question, rather than making us turn our heads and squint to try reading that image.

Comment: I am sorry Kyle. I was unaware of this.

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has mentioned it yet, but no me, this question does not appear to have any physical motivation and as a result, probably is not on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Using $f(t+p) = f(t)$, you easily get

$$\int_a^{a+p}f(x)dx = \int_a^pf(x)dx + \int_p^{a+p} f(x)dx = \int_a^pf(x)dx + \int_0^a f(t+p)dt=$$$$ = \int_a^pf(x)dx + \int_0^a f(t)dt = \int_0^pf(x)dx$$

And you can see that the last integral does not depend on $a$